# Found the error when I deploy the next.js app in cPannal

Tags: deployment, next.js, cpanel

I want to deploy my `next.js` app in cPannel. I follow all the steps but I received the errors in the `stderr.log` file. the errors is

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'next'
Require stack:
- /home/yourhikf/dev.yourguide.pk/server.js
- /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yourhikf/dev.yourguide.pk/server.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/yourhikf/dev.yourguide.pk/server.js',
    '/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js'
  ]
}
```

This is the error that is logged when I want to load the deployed site. The `package.json` file has the following packages

```
{
  "name": "yourguide-next-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.2.0",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "12.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tinymce": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.20.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.3"
  }
}
```

I am unable to solve the problem kindly tell me the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by entering the following commands in the terminal:

- npm update
- npm install